# Downward Rightarrow for natural transformation, tikzcd

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I am pretty sure this is out there on this site, but I did not find it after searching.

How to draw a downward

`\Rightarrow`

in a commutative `tikzcd`diagram?

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[d,Rightarrow]\\
Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}` and please make the last part of your question clearer.

Comment: Can you add an image, please to have a clear idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like many users do not really understand your second request. Even though [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, I am guessing that you are looking for `\arrow[d,Rightarrow]` and `\arrow[d,dash]`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\begin{document} 
\[
\begin{tikzcd} X \arrow[d,Rightarrow] & A \arrow[d,dash]\\ 
Y & B
\end{tikzcd} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for linked image